# QGIS pick up certain value from the nearest neighbour object

Tags: qgis, nearest-neighbor

I have a set of addresses defined by the green dot. I have also objects (poles) to which I would like to assign the address (3-4 data attribute columns) from the nearest address point (green).

[image]

I tried to use the [Nearest Neighbour analysis](https://www.qgistutorials.com/en/docs/3/nearest_neighbor_analysis.html) but I had a problem with the hub layer attribute, as I have to pick up just one.

How can I transfer interesting columns from the nearest point (different layer) to my layer?

**UPDATE:**

Maybe a more accurate image is below. I would like to have the address of the nearest point included in the point shown (different layer).

[image]

Comment: Look at `overlay_nearest` : https://docs.qgis.org/3.22/en/docs/user_manual/expressions/functions_list.html#overlay-nearest

Comment: OK, so now can I use this expression as a selection right?

Comment: What do you mean by "3-4 data attribute columns"?

Comment: I have address split by 3-4 columns: 1 - address line 1 2 address line 2, 3 - county, 4 postcode

Comment: so : `overlay_nearest('your_address_layer_name', addr_fld1 || ' ' || addr_fld2)[0]`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Open Field Calculator for "poles" layer and use this expression:

```
overlay_nearest(
    layer:='poles',
    expression:="address line 1" || ' ' || "address line 2" || ' ' || "county" || ' ' || "postcode"
)[0]
```

[image]

Comment: Looks nice! Where can I place it? I used the "Select by expression" option and this formula seems to be not valid. Is it the right place?

Comment: Ok. I've edited the answer

Comment: OK, many thanks. Now it makes sense. I think, that it applies to all expressions. Thet should go to the field calculator instead of the "Select by the expression" as I thought initially.

Answer (score 4):

I think I found the solution, which is explained in this article:

https://opensourceoptions.com/blog/spatial-joins-with-qgis-using-the-join-attributes-by-nearest-tool/

For the situations such as this we can use:
**Processing Toolbox -> Vector general -> Join attributes by nearest**

where we can clearly define the layer where we want to pick up our data (multiple columns) and the layer to which this data should be assigned.

By leaving the nearest neighbor as 1 we can get this data from the nearest item as requested.
[image]
[image]

and a new layer will include both Layer 1 attributes as well as assigned from the nearest object of the second layer.